# Generic method return super type of type param and method parameter type param

Tags: java, generics

I want the return type param to be super of both a type param and a method param's type param.

This compiles:

```
import java.util.List;
interface Foo<A> {
    <R, B extends R> List<R> eg1(List<B> unit);
    <R> List<R> eg2(List<? extends R> unit);
}
```

But it doesn't enforce that R must be a super of A also. How do I do that?

In effect, I want to do something like what is expressed in these:

```
<B, R super A & B> List<R> func(List<B> unit);
<B> List<? super A & B> func(List<B> unit);
```

But those don't compile, of course.

There are two purposes to this:

1. I want to be able to assign the result to any super class of both A and B.
2. In the implementation of this method, I need a result type that can include both A's and B's. So the first examples that do compile would not work because they would not allow me to put an A in the result.

Comment: If `R` is allowed to be any supertype of `A`, and `B` is allowed to be any subtype of `R`, then that's equivalent to just saying `B` is allowed to be anything, because `R` can always be `Object`.  What _actual task_ are you trying to accomplish that you think needs these generics?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added details to the question to answer the first part of your comment. As for the second... actually, I should have worked on that first. Implementing that interface leads to the problem and I think that answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LouisWasserman 's comment, I started thinking of the implementation which I should have done so first. Somewhere something has to specify the type to construct to return. Either hard-coded in the method implementation, specified as a type param, param type param, etc. And wherever that specification is, that's where one can define the generics correctly for this interface method.

In other words, what I was trying to do makes no sense because you cannot construct the return type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to name the type parameter at the class level:

```
import java.util.List;
interface Foo<Base, A extends Base> {
    <B extends Base> List<Base> eg1(List<B> unit);
    <R> List<R> eg2(List<? extends R> unit);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not interesting for what I'm trying to do. You have to specify the second type parameter.